# Modifying a domain class after objects have already been persisted with that class

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

This question is similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220505/how-do-you-modify-a-domain-class-in-grails).

Let us assume that I have made a Grails application and then, sometime down the road, I need to add a field to a domain class.  What would be the best way to add that field and have all the objects already persisted to the database be updated too?  Is there anyway to do this in Grails (currently using 1.3.7, but upgrading to 2.0 when it is stable) without manually accessing the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this plugin: http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration

Comment: Does your plugin have the same drawback of the other Liquibase plugins like [Autobase](http://www.grails.org/plugin/autobase) and [LiquiBase for Grails](http://www.grails.org/plugin/liquibase)? They do not allow Hibernate to create database, which is a minor annoyance, but still annoying. Also, just curious, what did the other plugins lack that drove you to create your own?

Comment: Autobase was abandoned, but had some good ideas. We wanted official, SpringSource-supported migration support, so we created the new plugin that has the best features of the existing plugins, plus some cool new ones like gorm-diff, which creates a changeset between the current code and a database.

Comment: No, the plugin won't create a database. This is possible, but is usually way more involved than regular table modifications. For example in MySQL it's a 1-line command, but also requires an additional grant statement so you can access the database. I'd prefer to let users do that since it's very usage-specific. Have you created a database (or schema) in Oracle? It's far from a 1-line command :)